# Update Mysql column field from a table based on user id

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-update

I am new to PHP and SQL, at the moment I am just learning and experimenting not worried about security side. I am trying to Update the username and email based on the user id. My table name is users, and the columns within this table are "id, username, email, password".

Now the query doesn't execute this is what I have done so far.

```
<?php
include("db_connect.php");
error_reporting(0);
$email = $_POST['email'];
$username= $_POST['username'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
$sql= "UPDATE users SET username= '.$username.' , email= '.$email.' WHERE id='.$id.' ";
if($_POST['submit']){
     if (mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {
          echo "<h3><center>User information Updated successfully</center></h3>";
     } 
     else {
          echo " Something went wrong ";
     }
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Add Data</title>
</head>
<body>   
    <form action="update.php" method="POST" style="font-size: 24px; margin-left: 50px;">
        <h4> update user info</h4>
        Username: <input type="text" name="username"  required><br><br>
        Email: <input type="email" name="email"  required><br><br>
        <input style="background:#2CDC10; font-size:18px;" type="submit" name="submit" value="update data"/>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: What exact error you are facing? Could you please show the error here?

Comment: it just jumps to something went wrong bit, i am not sure if my approach is correct.

Comment: how do you get the id of a user? it seems your post data has no id

Comment: you are missing the $id from post

Comment: Where you are posting the `id` field. As I can see in your form I can't find the `id` field.

Comment: do i need something like ID: <input type="id" name="id"  required>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main issue is that you are using the PHP concatenation syntax in your SQL string. This makes all your values incorrect and as such your `id` in `where` clause doesn't match any record so no records are updated. Your query should be

```
$sql= "UPDATE users SET username= '$username' , email= '$email' WHERE id='$id' ";
```

or

```
$sql= "UPDATE users SET username= '" .$username. "' , email= '" . $email . "' WHERE id='" .$id. "' ";
```

That would run but is open to SQL injections. You should use prepared statements, parameterize that, and use error reporting:

```
error_reporting(1);
if(isset($_POST['submit']){
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     $username= $_POST['username'];
     $id = $_POST['id'];
     $sql= "UPDATE users SET username=?, email=? WHERE id=?";
     $stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $sql)) {
     mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssi", $username, $email, $id);//third i assumes "id" is an integer
     $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
     if(!empty($result)) {
          echo "<h3><center>User information Updated successfully</center></h3>";
     } else {
          printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
     }
}
```

This is a rough untested answer. More information about prepared statements can be found here, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php.

Comment: Thanks  @user3783243  for your answer, you're correct ,  the . seemed to be one of the issue also i had id missing in the html form.  Next I am going to learn about error reporting and how to prevent sql injections.  Thanks for your answer and advice one again.